# Is it possible to include file in an include file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a basic page structure in php that contains include files for head and footer.
In the footer, i want to add an include file that will load only if  the page as the data-table class.
Something like:

```
if ($class == 'data-table')
    include(SHARED_PATH . '/load-datatables.php');
```

My goal is to load scripts only when needed. I'm a newby in PHP so I want to start with simple things.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Can you show where are you assigning $class variable to your page?

Comment: The best way to dynamically load files as needed is to use an autoloader. [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) for example does include one so I recommend getting started with making your project a composer project.

Comment: require_once or include_once doesn't include your file more than once.

Comment: I inserted a variable in the begining of the page like this:   $class =        "data-table";

And in my head-include, I inserted :
  <body class="<?php echo $class; ?>">

Maybe using composer will be a better solution  in the future, but for now, i want to keep it "newby simple"

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to search for the "data-table" class in the page using php that would be hard. Although here's what you can do.

Add a php variable that indicates whether the datatable class "data-table" is being used in the page

```
// index.php

<?php $pageUsesDataTable = true; ?>
...
...
<table class="data-table">.....</table>

// Then load the script if depending on the variable

if ($pageUsesDataTable)
    include(SHARED_PATH . '/load-datatables.php');
```

Or you could just check if the "data-table" class exists in the page, if so initialize the datatable if it is generic

```
// dTable.js or <script>

if($('.data-table').length != 0) {
  // initialize the datatable
}
```

Although there's always a cleaner approach out there, try to search deeper. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Put this variable in those pages where you want to include the php-file load-datatables:

```
$include_datatables_file = true;
```

Then include a generic file called checkinclude.php on all your pages:
**checkinclude.php:**

```
if (!isset($include_datatable_file)) {$include_datatable_file = false;}
if ($include_datatable_file === true) {
    include_once(SHARED_PATH . '/load-datatables.php');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

After Anurag's comment: Did you try it... Of course I did, but I didn't get the right path so it didn't work. Changed the path and it works as expected.
Like I said, it might not be the cleanest way or the best practice. But it works and it's easy to set up. Thanks for all answers!